# copy specific subfolders Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have a list of folders and sub-folders with files in arranged as follows:

abcd>>one, two, three,other,junk.

abcde>>one,two,three,junk,not needed

Essentially I want to copy only the subfolders and files contained that are named one,two, three and ignore all others. So for the first example the desired structure would be abcd>> one, two, three with appropriate files retained in folders one, two and three

```
import os,shutil
src = "C:\\Users\\EM\\Desktop\\files\\"
dest = "C:\\Users\\EM\\Desktop\\new_files\\"

shutil.copytree(scr,dest,ignore=None)
```

The above code copies all folders and subfolders however when I try to pass the name of a subfolder  in ignore I get an error. TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
    import os, shutil
src = "C:\\Users\\EM\\Desktop\\files\\"
dest = "C:\\Users\\EM\\Desktop\\new_files\\"

files_ignore="other"

shutil.copytree(src,dest,ignore=files_ignore)
```

any guidance would be most helpful

Comment: `ignore=files_ignore`: `files_ignore` must be a __callable__

Comment: callable as what a function?